# How to load vector with 501 elements into a matrix with 10 columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, vector

I have this code written so far:

```
getSymbols(Symbols="SPY", from="2012-01-01", to= "2013-12-31")
SPY=data.frame(SPY)

Data=matrix(SPY$SPY.Adjusted, ncol=10, byrow=T)
df=data.frame(Data)
```

the matrix is filled completly with values but I want the last 9 values to be NA. How can I stop the matrix from restarting the vector? So i should end with a 51x10 matrix with 10 values in the first 50 rows and the last row should be 1 value and 9 NAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to use `length<-` to append the `NA` at the end

```
library(quantmod)
Data <- matrix(`length<-`(SPY$SPY.Adjusted, 51 * 10), ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)
```

-testing

```
dim(Data)
#[1] 51 10
Data[51,]
#[1] 161.0724       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Comment: When I run this I am getting an error because of the ","  after SPY$SPY.Adjusted. Or I get an error saying it cannot fin the function "length="

Comment: @cdesvous can you please copy/paste the same code instead of changing the syntax from `length<-` to `length=`

Comment: @cdesvous the function I used is with the backquotes.  If you change it to a different one, it won't work

Comment: That did work now. Thank you! Just curious why doesnt it work with = instead of <-

Comment: @cdesvous because there is a function specifically on that